# Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Crm.PowerShell not installed error

Tags: powershell, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

Trying to script an upgrade for my Dynamics organization following this [TechNet blog](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/dn833062.aspx).

But running into the below error which I understand, but not sure the process to get the PSSnapin onto my system.

```
PS C:\Program Files\Dynamics SDK\SDK\Bin> Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Crm.PowerShell

Add-PSSnapin : The Windows PowerShell snap-in 'Microsoft.Crm.PowerShell' is not installed on this computer.
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Crm.PowerShell
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (Microsoft.Crm.PowerShell:String) [Add-PSSnapin], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AddPSSnapInRead,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddPSSnapinCommand
```

Comment: You can get the module from GitHub here: https://github.com/seanmcne/Microsoft.Xrm.Data.PowerShell/releases/

Answer (score 1):

First of all, sign in with the *Administrator* account on your *Microsoft Dynamics 365 server*.

Then in elevated mode Run

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Crm.PowerShell
```

If you have no registered then use the [Use PowerShell cmdlets for XRM tooling to connect to Dynamics 365](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn689040.aspx)

You can externally also download the same from GITHUB:
[Link provided by theMadTechnician](https://github.com/seanmcne/Microsoft.Xrm.Data.PowerShell/issues)

Hope it helps